# How can I add a button to quicktags-toolbar?

Tags: customization

I would like to add a button to this toolbar, right of "fullscreen":

[image]

The button should add this: „“

If text is selected, it should get around the text, like this: „selected text“

How can I add such a button to the ed_toolbar (class: quicktags-toolbar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following code in your function.php

```
add_action( 'admin_footer-post-new.php', 'wpse_64665_add_quick_tag' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php',     'wpse_64665_add_quick_tag' );
function wpse_64665_add_quick_tag() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        edButtons[edButtons.length] = new edButton( '„“', '„“', '„', '“', '' );
    </script><?php
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked fine. According to this page, I would have to give two more parameters: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action . Strange.

Comment: Those are optional paramaters and are not required for this example. You could play with the priority just incase.

Comment: Note that this is out of date, I think, and the preferred way is now via [QTags.addButton](https://codex.wordpress.org/Quicktags_API).

Answer (score 0):

The new, recommended way to add buttons to the toolbar is via the [Quicktags API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Quicktags_API). Furthermore the site GenerateWP provides a handy [code generator](https://generatewp.com/quicktags/), which for this example creates the following:

```
// Add Quicktags
function custom_quicktags() {
    if ( wp_script_is( 'quicktags' ) ) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    QTags.addButton( 'fancy_quote_button', '„“', '„', '“', '\"', 'Fancy quotes', 9 );
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'custom_quicktags' );
```

Note also that `QTags` also allows you to call JavaScript from buttons; the simplest example given is:

```
QTags.addButton( 'my_id', 'my button', my_callback );
function my_callback() { alert('yeah!'); }
```